# role based access using django-guardian

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-guardian

I am using django-guardian for giving role based permission and django-userena for user profiling. I have three kind of users Admin, sub-admin, employee. Admin can add sub-admin and sub-admin can add employees. I have created three groups in guardian for three user types. When user signup I assign that user an employee group.

```
class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    class Meta:
    permissions = ( 
                ( "add_admin", "Can add admin" ),
                ( "add_subadmin", "Can add sub admin" ),
                ( "add_employee", "Can add employee" ),
            )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                            unique=True,
                            verbose_name='user',
                            related_name='profile')
    first_name = models.CharField('First name',max_length=100,blank=False,null=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        employee_group = Group.objects.get('employee')
        self.groups.add(employee_group)
```

I want to use the Django Admin and give Admin and sub-admin the ability to change the user's group.

How can I add the drop down or radio buttons in the Admin panel using AdminModel so that I can change the user's group. Or is there any better approach to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looking for [Admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions), You have to write some custom admin actions.

#### Update

When you creating admin you can check if current `request.user` is able to see that actions. We can say like, If user is not a admin then custom action method should return `None` or just `pass`. There is an app for getting current user anywhere in the code, When you don't have access to your current user request, it's called [`django-cuser`](https://github.com/Alir3z4/django-cuser). It would be suitable for you case where you need to determine whether use is admin or sub-admin to make custom action available for him.

Start from [**Conditionally enabling or disabling actions**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#conditionally-enabling-or-disabling-actions)

Comment: Thanks for referring me Admin actions. But if I create any Admin action then it will be visible to every type of user.
for example I have three actions make_admin, make_sub_admin and make_employee. All three should be visible to Admin type user. Sub Admin user can see only mak_sub_admin and make_employee action. How can I do that. I want to use default Admin Template and do not want to write custom templates.